# hangman from 100 days of python solution

Tags: python

Is there a way to insert letters in a specific place where they (letters) are located inside a word?

This code allows me to do so, but adds `'_'` at the end of a list and misses the spot for a second letter if there are multiples of the same in one word. For example - pumpkin, it would add the first 'p' at its rightful place, but the second one will be right after.

These are my instructions:

> Use a while loop to let the user guess again. The loop should only stop once the user has guessed all the letters in the chosen_word and 'display' has no more blanks (`"_"`). Then you can tell the user they've won.

```
import random
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()

display = []
for i in chosen_word:
  if i ==guess:
    display.append(i)
  else:
    display.append('_')
print(display)
while '_' in display:
  guess = input("Guess a letter: ").lower()
  for i in chosen_word:
    if i ==guess:
      display.insert(chosen_word.index(i),i)
  print(display)
```

Comment: Not related to your problem but get rid of your first paragraph and start with `display == "_"*len(chosen_word)`, otherwise it's redundant with the second part.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It took me a little while to understand the question. Do you mean that you want to *replace* `_` symbols in the list with the appropriate letter? Well - normally, how do you set the value of an element of a list, given the index and the new value?

Comment: if you have list then you can do `display[index] = char`

Comment: maybe you should use `for index, char in enumerate(chosen_word): if char == guess: display[index] = char`. `index(i)` can find only first letter - or you would have to search in `.index(i, start_position)` to search in part after first char

Comment: sorry for the way i formulated the question. Yes, i do need to replace '_' symbol with a letter if the letter inputed by the user corresponds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.index(char)` always gives first position.
You would have to use `.index(char, start_position)` to search after first position

```
pos = chosen_word.index(char)         # first position
display.insert(pos, char)

pos = chosen_word.index(char, pos+1)  # second position 
display.insert(pos, char)

# etc.
```

You could try to do it in loop - and start with `pos = -1`

```
pos = -1

for ...:
    if  ...: 
        pos = chosen_word.index(char, pos+1)
        display[pos] = char
```

but it can be simpler to use

```
for index, char in enumerate(chosen_word): 
    if char == guess: 
        display[index] = char
```

---

```
import random

word_list = ["pumpkin", "aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

display = ['_'] * len(chosen_word)

print("".join(display))

while '_' in display:
  
    guess = input("Guess a letter: ")

    for index, char in enumerate(chosen_word):
        if char.lower() == guess.lower():
            display[index] = char

    print("".join(display))
```

Comment: thank you very much - it works perfectly, the way i intended. Now i just need to understand how, cause some of the terms are new to me

Comment: maybe use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is doing. You may also try to see it using page [PythonTutor](https://pythontutor.com/)